# External monitor works, but laptop shows purple screen

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

When I boot my laptop, I hear the login drum sound, but the screen remains on the purple startup screen with the ubuntu logo and the orange dots.  If I plug in an external monitor, it works fine, but the laptop monitor remains on the purple screen.

I can change the BIOS to "discrete graphics" and the external monitor and laptop screen work as expected.  If I change BIOS to "integrated graphics" I only get the laptop monitor, but it works.  The problem occurs in Optimus mode.

Optimus mode worked fine until some recent updates. Any ideas on how to start troubleshooting?  Or maybe things just need to be reset somehow?